# SystemDirectoryInfo no contiene una definicion .GetFiles C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

estoy tratando de validar si existen o no carpetas y abrir sus archivos que tienen dentro, pero me arroga un error al momento de utilizar el metodo .GetFiles

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy utilizando Visual Studio 2012, no se si el error pueda ser por la versión de mi VS, o cual método estaría bien usar para hacer la misma tarea del .GetFiles en la versión 2012

porque en VS 2017 me voy a la clase DirectoryInfo y me aparece el metodo .GetFiles por lo cual no me arroga error en el .GetFiles

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en la clase DirectoryInfo pero en VS 2012 no me aparece el metodo .GetFiles

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si se deba a las versiones de los visual studio

cualquier duda estaré al pendiente

Comment: El error es muy raro, ¿no estás en UNITIY verdad? Prueba quitando *var* y definiendo explicítamente DirectoryInfo folderPath = new DirectoryInfo(@'...');

Comment: No, no estoy en UNITY, ya probé tu solución pero me sigue arrogando el error, edite mi publicación y agregue unas imágenes comparando las clases DirectoryInfo tanto de VS 2017 y VS 2012

Comment: ¿Qué versión de .net estas usando, ya sea core, framework o standard?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal estoy usando la versión 5.0 (version 11.0.61219.00) y la version de .net 4.7.03190

Comment: Esa carpeta esta dentro de tu servidor dentro del proyecto? si es asi deverias usar el server.map

Comment: @EdgarVazquez no esa carpeta la tengo en un servidor, pero no dentro de mi proyecto

Comment: que raro.. segun la documentacion esa funcion esta en todas las versiones de .net

Comment: Y por favor no dupliques tus preguntas! solo generas mas trabajo de limpieza

Comment: ¿Es una solución con un solo proyecto? ¿Podrías agregar como está formada tu solución?

Comment: ¿No se podrá hacer una actualización de alguna DLL o alguna otra cosa o reinstalar VS 2012?

Comment: Hola @eddyKroz, veo que en la imagen de la parte de Vs2012 la versión de mscorlib es la 2.0.5.0.puedes verificar si es la misma o no en tu VS2017?

Comment: Hola @SergioParraGuerra efectivamente, en mi VS 2012 tengo la versión 2.0.5.0 y en VS 2017 tengo la versión 4.0.0.0, se puede actualizar el mscorlib de mi VS 2012 a la version 4.0.0.0?

Comment: Hola, comprueba la versión del. Net framework de destino de ese proyecto en Vs2012. Puedes mostrarnos el csproj?